# uncompress .z file using python?

Tags: python, subprocess, compression

I am trying to uncompress file using 7z in Python. I tried tarfile, zipfile other utilities also but none was working. Here what the directory structure looks like : 
G:\a\b\c.z
after uncompression, it becomes: 
G:\a\b\c.txt

I came across the use of subprocess:
    import subprocess
    exe='C:\7z.exe'
    source='G:\a\b\c.z'
    target='G:\a\b'
    subprocess.call ( ???)

What should I write here. I came across code for compression but dont know how to do decompression. 
Please help.The number of files is huge and I have been trying this for days now.

In windows command line also , it is unable to extract the file though it lists the file in the archive.

Comment: Check this answer, it is for compressing but is valid for your case http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466648/1782792

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/lzma.html

Comment: @javidcf I tried what was there. I did something like this :         for file in glob.glob('*.Z'):
 newfile=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
 subprocess.call([exe, 'a', file, newfile])         it produced following output : 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 I dont know this is for what. However, files didnt get decompressed.

Comment: @Vidhi I was referring to the answer that suggest using [pyzlma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma/) and [py7zlib](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/py7zlib.py) (or [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) if you are in Python 3, as suggested by Tichodroma).

Comment: Include the first few bytes of an example file in hex in your question.

Comment: Use the raw path to the executable (`r'C:\7z.exe'`), and are you absolutely sure the binary is in the `C:\` drive?

Comment: I tried downloading pyzlma but it failed. I think using subprocess was the easiest way to do but even in windows command prompt it is not decompressing the file

Comment: @Burhan yes because when i ran the command on windows command line, it listed the file in the archive but it did not decompress it.

Comment: Still waiting for the first few bytes ...

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your response but its done :) :). I tried os.system() in the python script.Thanks all for your responses